# Traveling to Italy from USA with Italian Passport near Expiration

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, italy, italian-citizens

Traveling to Italy from the US with an Italian passport that will have less than 3 months left before expiration upon arrival in Italy **and** will also have a valid US Green Card with no expiration impending. I will return to US before six weeks before Italian Passport Expires.

1. Will I have issues with departure from the US and entry into
   Italy?
2. Will I have issues with departure from Italy and re-entry into the US?

Just trying to figure out whether it is worth trying to renew my passport before I leave for Italy.

Answer (score 5):

This should be okay in both directions.

Rules that require additional future validity of passports never apply *for entering the country that issued the passport*. It would be pointless for them to do -- countries have such rules to make sure they can send visitors back to their home country, but that only works if the passport *is still good for the home country all the way up to the date written on it*. If Italy wanted the passport to lose power completely three months earlier, they would just have issued it with an earlier date of expiry in the first place!

(This works for the entire Schengen area, by the way. The usual three-months requirement applies only to *third-country* passports in the first place).

As for going back to the US, there are three independent reasons why you should have no problems:

- Passports issued by Italy are **exempted** from the "six months or remaining validity" requirement in the first place.
- The six-month rule only applies to **non-immigrant** visitors, not to permanent legal residents. (8 U.S.C. §1182(a)(7)(B)(i)(I)).
- You can enter on your **green card** alone without showing the Italian passport at all.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications, much appreciated.